# What's the difference between itemAt() and takeAt() in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

**Note:**
I'm working on a Windows 10 machine with Python 3.7 installed. I use PyQt5 to build my GUI's.

When you've got a `QLayout()`-instance holding some widgets and sublayouts, you can iterate over them with the following functions:

- `itemAt()` takes an index as parameter, and returns the corresponding `QLayoutItem()`-instance. If it's a widget, you can get hold on it by simply applying the `widget()` function on the returned value. If it's a sub-layout, you can equally get hold on it by applying the `layout()` function. (doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#itemAt)

  ```
  myWidget    = myLayout.itemAt(i).widget()
  mySublayout = myLayout.itemAt(j).layout()
  ```
- `takeAt()` looks the same. It also takes an index as parameter and returns the corresponding `QLayoutItem()`-instance. (doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt)

So, what's the difference?

Comment: Why not just [look at the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt)?

Comment: I did, but I didn't see a clear difference between them.

Comment: To me, the difference between "remove" and "return" seems very clear. Also "take" seems to give quite a strong hint.

Comment: Okay, got it. The `takeAt()` actually returns and removes the item. Sorry I didn't see that before :-)